# Engagement Split with more than 1 required clicks in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Regarding den Engagements Split,

If 4 dedicated links must be clicked (AND) to proceed with the yes branch, do I need to use 4 engagement splits in a row or is there a more simple approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you will need to use four different engagement splits; that's how I have been doing it at least. [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_use_the_engagement_split_activity.htm&type=5) is the documentation on engagement splits for more info. It does not specifically address your issue, but it mentions it's "an email" not multiple unfortunately.